# Access Add-on preferences property in a multi-file add-on

Tags: python, add-on

I have a multi-file/multi-folder add-on, with preferences properties created in a prefs.py.

```
import bpy

class AddonPreferences(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __package__

    my_property : bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name = "my_bool",
    )
```

I can easily access this bool in my __init__.py with:

```
bpy.context.preferences.addons[__package__].preferences.my_property
```

But I can't manage to access it in panel.py placed in a UI folder. What is the correct way to call that property in a multi-file add-on?

Comment: I would guess those properties should be declared in a class, which is registered on blender startup?

Comment: Yes I declare them in the __init__.py file:
`bpy.utils.register_class (prefs.AddonPreferences)`


But if I try to call them in my other files I get a KeyError:
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "myaddon.ui.panel" not found'

Comment: @chafouin What is the value of `__package__` in prefs.py?

Comment: @batFINGER Is it something I have to define manually?

Comment: @batFINGER Printing it from the prefs.py returns the name of my top folder, which is the name of my addon (in that case, photographer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All credit goes to [Machin3io](https://twitter.com/machin3io) (creator of [Machin3 Tools](https://machin3.gumroad.com/l/MACHIN3tools), [Decal Machine](https://machin3.gumroad.com/l/DECALmachine) etc) since I learned about this by studying his code.

```
#This code assumes your folder name is the name of your addon
#It also assumes that this function is placed inside a .py file in the base folder

#get the folder path for the .py file containing this function
def get_path():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


#get the name of the "base" folder
def get_name():
    return os.path.basename(get_path())


#now that we have the addons name we can get the preferences
def get_prefs():
    return bpy.context.preferences.addons[get_name()].preferences
```

You can now use this function to get the preferences from anywhere you want by importing this function

If you want to read about `os.path` you can do so [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Answer (score 2):

My workaround was to have all the python files in a single folder and avoid subfolders. That way `__package__` was returning the proper add-on name. This is not a real solution though.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across the same issue while developing an addon. I got a workaround from looking at [this](https://github.com/LuxCoreRender/BlendLuxCore/blob/master/ui/addon_preferences.py#L13) code of BlendLuxcore: use a mixture of `basename` and `dirname` from `os.path` to get to the folder name of your addon.

Answer (score 0):

After observing how `__init__.py` packages everything together this simple trick worked. Please do let me know if some other correction is needed.

```
My folder structure:
my_addon/__init__.py
my_addon/somefunc.py
my_addon/anotherfunc.py
my_addon/somefolder/otherfunc.py
```

The folder name (my_addon) should have pythonic name (no period, slash etc).

Now in `__init__.py` I put this simple import:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "My addon",
    "version": (3, 0),
    "blender": (2, 90, 3),
    "category": "Sequencer",
    }

# this (from . import) go up one folder 
#and will import the modules from that folder. 
#As a result will recognize as a package.

from . import somefunc, anotherfunc
from .somefolder import otherfunc



modules = (somefunc, anotherfunc, otherfunc)


def register():
    for m in modules:
        m.register()


def unregister():
    for m in modules:
        m.unregister()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 0):

As CybranM's approved answer didn't work for me, I used Blender's own [AddonPreference API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AddonPreferences.html) to get the value I wanted like this:

```
import bpy

addon_prefs = bpy.context.preferences.addons['<addon-name>'].preferences
# Assuming the preference is a boolean value named is_installed
preference_value = addon_prefs.is_installed
```

I simply replaced `<addon-name>` with the name of my addon.
This should ideally work in basically any file regardless of file structure as long as you import bpy.

For reference my blender version is 3.3.1